# IabHelper queryInventory() returns basic prices for products

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, payment

In my case I have In-App Product on PlayStore and setup different prices for different countries. Next, whenever I'm fetching products using `IabHelper.queryInventory()` the price of the product is a base price and not for specific country.

Base price is 12.99 Euro and the price for my country is 9.99 Euro. `IabHelper.queryInventory()` returns a response with the price 12.99 Euro. But when I do a purchase and see the dialog from PlayStore it shows that the actual price is 9.99 Euro.

Is it an issue in IabHelper or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that setting in-app billing different prices is only available in some countries:  https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1169947?hl=en

> If you're in a location that supports [merchant registration](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/table/3539140), you
>   can offer apps in multiple currencies through the Google Play
>   Developer Console.

You can query Google Play to programmatically retrieve details of the in-app products that are associated with your application

Setup `queryInventoryAsync`

```
  mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, additionalSkuList, mQueryFinishedListener);
```

Retrieve the item prices from the result set

```
 IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mQueryFinishedListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
 public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {
     if (result.isFailure()) {
        // handle error
        return;
      }

     String firstItemPrice= inventory.getSkuDetails(YOUR_SKU_ONE).getPrice();
     String NthItemPrice = inventory.getSkuDetails(YOUR_SKU_N).getPrice();

   // update the UI
  }
}
```

Check this reference for more details. https://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/list-iab-products.html#QueryDetails

The `getSkuDetails()` method.

This method returns product details for a list of product IDs. In the response Bundle sent by Google Play, the query results are stored in a String ArrayList mapped to the DETAILS_LIST key. Each String in the details list contains product details for a single product in JSON format. Check [this API reference](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html#getSkuDetails) for more details

Comment: yes, that's what I'm trying. and `queryInventoryAsync` returns basic price for the product. Country and locale does't matter in this case  unless user starts purchase with PlayStore. `getSkuDetails()` always returns same price.